# ImportError during .exe file creation with PyInstaller

Tags: python, pyinstaller

I am trying to create an .exe file from my python script to enable my coworker who doesn't have Python installed to run the file locally. The file runs plotly/dash visualization in a browser window. I'm trying it with PyInstaller; below are the import error statements I'm getting:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\ishulman\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3_1505\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\__init__.py", line 141, in <module>
    from . import cbook, rcsetup
  File "C:\Users\ishulman\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3_1505\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\cbook\__init__.py", line 33, in <module>
    import numpy as np
  File "C:\Users\ishulman\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3_1505\lib\site-packages\numpy\__init__.py", line 140, in <module>
    from . import _distributor_init
  File "C:\Users\ishulman\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3_1505\lib\site-packages\numpy\_distributor_init.py", line 34, in <module>
    from . import _mklinit
ImportError: DLL load failed: Das angegebene Modul wurde nicht gefunden.
739146 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-matplotlib.py"...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\ishulman\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3_1505\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\__init__.py", line 141, in <module>
    from . import cbook, rcsetup
  File "C:\Users\ishulman\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3_1505\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\cbook\__init__.py", line 33, in <module>
    import numpy as np
  File "C:\Users\ishulman\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3_1505\lib\site-packages\numpy\__init__.py", line 140, in <module>
    from . import _distributor_init
  File "C:\Users\ishulman\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3_1505\lib\site-packages\numpy\_distributor_init.py", line 34, in <module>
    from . import _mklinit
ImportError: DLL load failed: Das angegebene Modul wurde nicht gefunden.
739647 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-numpy.core.py"...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 2, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\ishulman\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3_1505\lib\site-packages\numpy\__init__.py", line 140, in <module>
    from . import _distributor_init
  File "C:\Users\ishulman\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3_1505\lib\site-packages\numpy\_distributor_init.py", line 34, in <module>
    from . import _mklinit
ImportError: DLL load failed: Das angegebene Modul wurde nicht gefunden.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\ishulman\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3_1505\lib\pkgutil.py", line 493, in find_loader
    spec = importlib.util.find_spec(fullname)
  File "C:\Users\ishulman\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3_1505\lib\importlib\util.py", line 94, in find_spec
    parent = __import__(parent_name, fromlist=['__path__'])
  File "C:\Users\ishulman\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3_1505\lib\site-packages\numpy\__init__.py", line 140, in <module>
    from . import _distributor_init
  File "C:\Users\ishulman\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3_1505\lib\site-packages\numpy\_distributor_init.py", line 34, in <module>
    from . import _mklinit
ImportError: DLL load failed: Das angegebene Modul wurde nicht gefunden.

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\ishulman\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3_1505\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\utils\hooks\__init__.py", line 320, in get_module_file_attribute
    loader = pkgutil.find_loader(package)
  File "C:\Users\ishulman\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3_1505\lib\pkgutil.py", line 499, in find_loader
    raise ImportError(msg.format(fullname, type(ex), ex)) from ex
ImportError: Error while finding loader for 'numpy.core' (<class 'ImportError'>: DLL load failed: Das angegebene Modul wurde nicht gefunden.)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\ishulman\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3_1505\Scripts\pyinstaller-script.py", line 10, in <module>
    sys.exit(run())
  File "C:\Users\ishulman\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3_1505\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\__main__.py", line 111, in run
    run_build(pyi_config, spec_file, **vars(args))
  File "C:\Users\ishulman\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3_1505\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\__main__.py", line 63, in run_build
    PyInstaller.building.build_main.main(pyi_config, spec_file, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\ishulman\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3_1505\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\build_main.py", line 838, in main
    build(specfile, kw.get('distpath'), kw.get('workpath'), kw.get('clean_build'))
  File "C:\Users\ishulman\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3_1505\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\build_main.py", line 784, in build
    exec(text, spec_namespace)
  File "<string>", line 17, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\ishulman\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3_1505\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\build_main.py", line 241, in __init__
    self.__postinit__()
  File "C:\Users\ishulman\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3_1505\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\datastruct.py", line 158, in __postinit__
    self.assemble()
  File "C:\Users\ishulman\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3_1505\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\build_main.py", line 500, in assemble
    module_hook.post_graph()
  File "C:\Users\ishulman\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3_1505\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\imphook.py", line 410, in post_graph
    self._load_hook_module()
  File "C:\Users\ishulman\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3_1505\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\imphook.py", line 377, in _load_hook_module
    self.hook_module_name, self.hook_filename)
  File "C:\Users\ishulman\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3_1505\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\compat.py", line 736, in importlib_load_source
    return mod_loader.load_module()
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 407, in _check_name_wrapper
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 907, in load_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 732, in load_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 265, in _load_module_shim
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 696, in _load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 677, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 728, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "C:\Users\ishulman\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3_1505\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\hooks\hook-numpy.core.py", line 27, in <module>
    pkg_base, pkg_dir = get_package_paths('numpy.core')
  File "C:\Users\ishulman\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3_1505\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\utils\hooks\__init__.py", line 537, in get_package_paths
    file_attr = get_module_file_attribute(package)
  File "C:\Users\ishulman\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3_1505\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\utils\hooks\__init__.py", line 339, in get_module_file_attribute
    raise ImportError
ImportError
```

All the libraries are installed, the path is correct and the code is running on my computer. Researching online I understand this has to do with hidden imports; still I couldn't find a solution of how to fix for my libraries. I'd appreciate any leads. Also, are there any alternative/easier ways to get the python script running locally without a Python installation?

Comment: create an executable using Pyinstaller or py2exe. Find more here : https://docs.python-guide.org/shipping/freezing/

Comment: I totally forgot to mention it, sorry: I'm doing it with Pyinstaller; the errors I'm getting are at the exe creation stage.

Answer (score 0):

PyInstaller's official website has an article about hidden imports, see if it helps.

https://pyinstaller.org/en/stable/when-things-go-wrong.html?highlight=hidden%20imports#listing-hidden-imports

The page explains how to list hidden imports and make Analysis find them during creation of the .exe

If Analysis thinks it has found all the imports, but the app fails with an import error, the problem is a hidden import; that is, an import that is not visible to the analysis phase.

Hidden imports can occur when the code is using **import**(), importlib.import_module() or perhaps exec() or eval(). Hidden imports can also occur when an extension module uses the Python/C API to do an import. When this occurs, Analysis can detect nothing. There will be no warnings, only an ImportError at run-time.

To find these hidden imports, build the app with the --debug=imports flag and run it.

Once you know what modules are needed, you add the needed modules to the bundle using the --hidden-import command option, or by editing the spec file, or with a hook file.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33435671)

Comment: ok is it better now?